# Get MYSQL last updated data or lastly inserted data

Tags: java, mysql, database, multithreading, listener

I have some problem like this.

I am accessing a database which is currently having over 100,000 data in ***new entry*** table.

Now I want to write a listener, means if any new record insert to table from somewhere else I have to get a **notification**.

My question is: What is best and fastest way to do this? because for a day there should have around 500 new data in the ***new entry*** table. Is is suitable to check the database every time using a thread?

Im using Java to do this with MySQL.

Please advice me.

Comment: Clarification: what is updating the table, exactly? If entries are inserted via a Java application, you can use something like JMS to send a message every time an insert is done. If not, you'll have to use a MySQL message queue, which is a plugin to MySQL. You can also turn on and monitor the binary log.

Comment: This database developed with PHP application and data insertion part comes with the PHP application.(PHP application is a network application and over 1000 users are accessing it.). What I want to capture is if there is any new record assigned for a person I have to get it.I want to write a program in java, if there is a new record for a particular person I have to make a pop up. Therefore I have to check the DB every time to give the popup message.

Comment: Seems like MySQL message queue is your best bet. I'm not too familiar with it to give more advice though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether there is any listener that exists for Mysql changes. So it wouldn't be straight forward to get these details.

But there is something called '[The Binary Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-log.html)' in mysql, which contains “events” that describe database changes such as table creation operations or changes to table data.

So one way to track the changes can be polling these logs. The challenge is that these logs are written in binary format. Mysql provides a utility called [mysqlbinlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) to process these logs in text format.

Here is one java parser for your rescue, which can read the mysql binary logs:

https://github.com/tangfl/jbinlog

Integrating all this bits and pieces , you may be able to get what you need.

Comment: Cant I do this using any sql query?

Comment: @RakithaFernando I don't think so. If you are the owner of the database then you can limit the access to it through a unified interface like an API. And then you can log the details as you need.

Comment: I did something like this, I wrote a resultset to get max id then I put it into arraylist. Then i check If the first value and the last value are equals. If they are not equal that means table updated with new record.Totally working fine,but Im wondering about the data speed now...

Answer (score 0):

try out this...

```
numero = stmt.executeUpdate(query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
```

Take a look at the documentation for the JDBC Statement interface.

Answer (score 0):

I used java timer class for as an alternative to this solution. Now it works fine. It checks the database in every 10 seconds and if the condition true, it will execute what I want.